# Traveling from Kobe to KIX airport to catch early morning flight

Tags: japan, kix

I have a 9:30AM international flight from KIX airport. I intend to stay at Kobe the night before. I've read that the ferry service from Kobe to KIX takes about 30 minutes and is convenient.

Is this ferry service accessible to anyone (do I need to enter UKB to board the ferry)?

Is catching the 6AM ferry reasonable, or is it too tight?

Comment: @jmac may know?

Comment: For future viewers, I took a cab to the ferry terminal and reached KIX via ferry. The ferry service was fast and reached before schedule. They have shuttles that take ferry passengers to the KIX terminals from the jetty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been on this ferry before. It is quite efficient -- check their schedule, but I suspect that it will arrive before 7:00. If it were me, I'd be willing to do it.

It's slightly a pain to get to the ferry terminal from, e.g. Sannomiya; the train that goes to the terminal is less convenient than most Japanese trains. I would encourage you to either take a cab or double check the train schedule the day before if you take the train.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's "tight" in the sense that you have zero leeway for problems. It's Japan, so things generally run as scheduled. You need 2 hours at the airport so it's possible.

Any reason you don't stay at a KIX hotel instead of Kobe?

Comment: I am attending an event in Kobe, and don't want to book another hotel near KIX for a single night.

Comment: Check the weather. If there's any chance of stormy weather, then take the train or taxi instead.

Answer (score 2):

The most sensible way to go between KIX and central Kobe city (*i.e.*, Sannomiya station) is definitely by [direct bus](http://www.kate.co.jp/en/timetable/detail/KB), unless of course you have a rail pass which makes trains "free", but even then you might still want to take the bus for convenience.

To go from Sannomiya to KIX by ferry involves at least two transfers: first you take the Port Liner to UKB, then possibly a shuttle bus to the ferry terminal (though you can also walk), then the ferry to KIX, and then another shuttle bus to the airport terminal (no walking).

Taking a taxi from Sannomiya to the ferry terminal at UKB sounds like a waste of money to me, as it is already much more expensive than the bus to KIX.